# Unable to move row from one datatable to another

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I have asked a question previously based on the errors of this code. However, after the suggestions given, there is no more error. However, the data from the row in queue table would not move to the the missedQueue table.

I'm not sure why it won't work :(

this is my code:

```
        DataSet queue = DBMgr.GetDataSet("SELECT * FROM queue");
        DataTable missedQueue = queue.Tables[0].Clone();

        DataRow dr = queue.Tables[0].NewRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < queue.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++)
        {
           dr[queue.Tables[0].Columns[i].ColumnName] = queue.Tables[0].Rows[0][i];
        }

        missedQueue.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);

    }
```

Comment: It seems you are trying to copy content of one datatable to another. If that the case then `DataTable missedQueue = queue.Copy()` is what you need to use. [DataTable.Copy Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal there is an error on 'queue.Copy()'

Comment: If possible please share error description.

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal there is no error description shown but it was underlined in red

Comment: @user8090359 copy is a method on DataTable, queue is a dataset(collection of tables), which you should already know since you're using  "queue.Tables[0]" with clone

Comment: @user6144226 I am actually not really good in programming that is why i needed much help. Thanks for the clarification^^

Comment: What @user8090359 mentioned is correct. I missed **"Tables[0]"** in my previous comment. **Correction:**   `DataTable missedQueue = queue.Tables[0].Copy();`.

Answer (score 0):

Your DataRow should be of `missedQueue` table and add the row inside loop like

```
    DataRow dr = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < queue.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++)
    {
       dr = missedQueue.NewRow();
       dr[queue.Tables[0].Columns[i].ColumnName] = queue.Tables[0].Rows[0][i]; 
       missedQueue.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
```

Comment: it still didn't transfer to the missedQueue table :(

Comment: OP loop is on columns and not rows